# Pandas unique() only returns scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

> I have a dataframe full_2020 with column 'Midpoint' containing values
> between 19 and 400000 (float64).   I've tried many ways to disable
> scientific notation but I keep getting the same result, along the
> lines of:
>
> ```
> pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
> full_2020['Midpoint'].unique()
> ```
>
> All attempts lead to output like this:
>
> array([1.65000e+05, 2.70400e+01, 1.92300e+01, 7.01250e+04,
> 6.00000e+04,
> 1.12500e+05, 1.26375e+05, 7.25000e+04, 1.54500e+05, 2.89500e+05,
> 1.52500e+05, 8.90000e+04, 1.14625e+05, 2.10000e+05, 2.75000e+05,
> 2.25000e+05, 2.35000e+05, 2.45000e+05, 1.20000e+05, 1.78000e+05,
> 1.21750e+05, 9.00000e+04, 1.00000e+05, 1.90000e+05, 2.57375e+05,
> 0.00000e+00, 1.00750e+05, 7.72500e+04, 1.40000e+05, 3.00000e+05,
> 2.01125e+05, 1.10000e+05, 4.00000e+05, 1.95000e+05, 5.62500e+04,
> 7.26250e+04, 1.45000e+05, 1.25000e+05, 1.05000e+05, 2.29250e+05,
> 1.84750e+05, 2.88500e+01, 2.48200e+01, 5.50000e+04, 2.15000e+05,
> 2.00000e+05, 2.50000e+05, 1.60000e+05, 2.20000e+05, 3.25000e+05])
>
> I only have this issue when using unique(), is there any way around
> this?

Comment: What float format do you want?

Comment: `array` is a numpy type. display.float_format probably only works with pandas types: Series and DataFrame. You could try this instead: `pd.Series(full_2020['Midpoint'].unique())`

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid this solved my problem.  If you change your comment to an answer I will mark it as solved.